# How to use memcache with SailsJS models?

Tags: mysql, node.js, memcached, sails.js

Are solutions for use with Nodejs MySQL, but I found no possibility to fasten them to the models have sailsjs.
How to cache database queries mysql? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your [own Sails adapter](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/adapters/custom-adapters) for MySQL with cache support using existing [sails-mysql adpater](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql). Basically you need to extend `find` method with caching functionality.

Comment: @Roman did you end up writing your own adapter? If you did, is it publicly available?